# A student had to solve $26$ problems.how many problems successfully solved and how many wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, puzzle

A student had to solve $26$ problems.His father promised that he will give him $800$ euro for every problem that we would solve correctly,but he would abstract $500$ euro for every problem that would be wrong.Finally the father estimated the correct  and wrong problems and noticed  that his son should not either get ,or give money.How many problems successfully solved and how many wrong?

Any ideas how to approach it?

Comment: Any ideas of your own on this?

Comment: Suppose student solved $c$ problems correctly and $w$ problems were wrong. What relations between $c$ and $w$ you can write?

Comment: Unless the problems are actually economically important to get solved in real life, it sounds completely disproportionate to let 1300 euro ride on each of them. I wonder what [parenting.SE] would say to that... seems like it would give the student a really unrealistic impression of how much his work is worth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ be the number of problems he solved. Then $26-x$ is the number of problems he didn't solve. Then, from the task: $0=x*800-(26-x)*500$. I am sure you can continue from here.